# Como popular uma classe com uma Lista de strings C#

Tags: c#, .net

No sistema que estou desenvolvimento eu envio de um select com múltiplas opções para uma lista do tipo string no meu controller, preciso agora vincular essa lista que recebo da view a lista com a classe login que tenho no meu model. O objetivo e que cada posição da lista de string vire uma posição na nova lista.

Por exemplo eu recebo a seguinte lista com os valores que foram enviados do select da view:

[0] = "147"

[1] = "56"

Eu preciso vincular esse array a minha outra lista de login, algo como assim

Login[0] = "147

Login[1] = "56"

vou colocar meus códigos com comentarios para explicar melhor:

View:

```
<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-live-search="true" asp-for="ListaResponsaveis">
   <option value="147">João</option>
   <option value="212">Maria</option>
   <option value="33">Luiza</option>
</select>
```

Model:

```
//Aqui recebo as opções marcadas no select
public List<string> ListaResponsaveis { get; set; }

//Quero passar a lista que recebi da view para essa lista
public List<Responsaveis> ListaResponsaveisData { get; set; }
    
public class Responsaveis
{
   public string Login { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> CadastrarTarefa([FromForm] WebdeskTarefas webdeskTarefas)
{
//Criei essa variavel para receber os dados da outra lista
var ListaResponsaveis = webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveisData;

//Aqui tentei vincular cada possição do array da lista da view a minha lista, porém ele não mostra valor no webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis[i]
for (int i = 0; i < webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis.Count; i++)
{
   ListaResponsaveis[i].Login = webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ListaResponsaveis** não é uma lista ja populada pelo select e que pertence a classe webdeskTarefas?

A idéia não era popular **webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveisData**?

Se for realmente isso seu código não faz muito sentido.
Se entendi bem o que deseja fazer, eu faria dessa forma:

```
//Considerando que o parâmetro **webDeskTarefas** tenha como atributo a lista **ListaResponsaveis** e que esteja populada com os valores do select
public async Task<IActionResult> CadastrarTarefa([FromForm] 
WebdeskTarefas webdeskTarefas)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis.Count; i++) //com a lista webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis ja populada pelo select
    {
       Responsaveis responsavel = new Responsaveis()
       {
           login = webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis[i]
       };
       webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveisData.Add(responsavel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sim o ListaResponsaveis já vem populada, porém eu quero passar o conteúdo dela para a webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveisData, ja que não consigo fazer isso direto da view para o controller. Ai preciso que cada array da webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveisData seja preenchido com o valor correspondente da ListaResponsaveis . O seu codigo deu o mesmo problema do meu, webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis[i] vem sempre com o valor "0", ele não esta pegando o valor da posição no array

Comment: Bom, acredito que não tenha erros na parte de popular a List<Responsaveis>ListaResponsaveisData com os elementos da List<string>ListaResponsaveis que seria o tema da pergunta. Provavelmente só está chegando '0' porque a lista não foi populada corretamente, deve ter sido instanciado as posições da lista mas não foi atribuido nenhum valor. Verifique debugando passo a passo se webdeskTarefas.ListaResponsaveis realmente chega populada com os valores corretos ao método CadastrarTarefa.

Comment: Debugando aqui descobri que quando ele tenta adicionar eu recebo o erro "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"